# Best practice to implement HttpServletRequest in Struts2?

Tags: struts2

What is best practice to implement HttpServletRequest in Struts2?

1. ServletActionContext - directly accessing the getRequest method from the ServletActionContext class
2. ServletRequestAware : the action class implements ServletRequestAware interface

Comment: Also, if you feel the interface way is better but want to avoid annoying code repetitions, just put the interface and the setter in the BaseAction extended by the others, only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see (or find documentation about) the benefits of 2. vs 1.

So why should I prefer

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
}
```

When is worth enough

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```